# Check if a set of keys exists in a result set

Tags: mysql, sql

In a simplified rental system, there are three relations:

- Book: id, title, description
- Copy: id, book_id
- Booking: id, copy_id, rent_from, rent_until

For each book there exist many copies. If a customer rents a book, an available copy is selected and a corresponding booking record is created.

Now my problem: A customer selects a book, he/she wants to rent. The system needs to check, which copies are available for the given rental period.

What is the most elegant and fastest way to query the available copies?

Basically, step-by-step one would do the following:

1. Select all copies of the corresponding book
2. Select all bookings in the specified period of those copies
3. Check which copies of the book are not included in the selected bookings. If all copies are included, the book is not available for rent in the given period

Step 3 gives my a headache. How to do this in SQL? Can I probably even perform all three steps in one elegant query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have the bookid.  You are looking for:

```
select c.*
from copies c
where not exists (select 1
                  from booking b
                  where b.copy_id = c.id and
                        b.rent_until >= @PeriodStart and b.rent_from <= @PeriodEnd
                 );
```

This is checking for overlapping time periods.  There is an overlap if the booking ends after the period starts and if the booking starts before the period ends.  The comparisons might be `<` and `>`, depending on whether a book can be rented on the `rent_until` date, or if it has to wait until the next day.